# i can not retrieve amount from database using oops concept

Tags: php, mysql, oop

there is i make a project in oops concept of php. i make two file one fro connection amothe html i want to print my dat on html file the last row using php print amount here html code

```
 <?php
    include('connection.php');
    $obj=new connect;

    $x=$obj->search();
    while($row = MySQLi_Result($x))
    {
        echo $row['amount'];
    }
     ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    Your Amount 
    <input type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo date("d-m-y");?>"/>
    <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" />

    <a href="add.php">add</a>
    <a href="subtract.php">subtract</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

here my connection.php

```
 <?php 
    //con.php

        class connect
        {
            var $conn;
            function __construct()
            {
                $this->conn=new MySQLi("localhost","root","","project111");
            }

            function add($date,$amount,$d)  
            {
                $addData=$this->conn->prepare('INSERT INTO `totalamount` (`date`,`amount`,detail)values (?,?,?)');
                $addData->bind_param('sss',$date,$amount,$d);
                $addData->execute();
            }

            function search()
            {
                $search=$this->conn->prepare('select * from `totalamount`');
                $search->execute();
                }
        }



        ?>
```

Comment: Its not `oops` ;), its `OOP`

Answer (score 1):

Your `search()` method does not return anything. Yet you assign its output to `$x` and try to use it afterwards. I guess you want to return the mysqli result handle which you'd have to fetch first...

That also shows that it is not a good idea not to do any error detection and handling. Before using `$x` you should check what it contains! If it is not a valid mysqli resource handle, then something has gone wrong and there is no sense in trying to use it in a subsequent mysqli retrieval command.

The third problem is that `mysqli_result()` does *not* return a row from the result set as you appear to expect.

I suggest you study a few more examples of working code and especially the documentation of the mysqli extension (it also carries examples).

Answer (score -2):

you must have write return within a function then you can cat all the values in an array forms.

This is write syntax :

return $search->execute();

Comment: it will return bool not the row or array

Comment: that means it is returning resource id you need to convert in an array.